# Google maps API: JSON to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm having trouble getting my markers to show up using Google Maps API V3.

This is my JavaScript:

```
function getMap(zoom, center) {
var myOptions = {
    zoom: zoom,
    center: center,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: centerBegin })
$.getJSON('json/markers.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, marker) {

        var markerOptions = { map: map, position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longtitude) , title: 'test'};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
        /*var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longtitude),
            content: i.toString(),
            map: map,
            title: 'test'
        });*/
    });
});
```

}

Here is my JSON file:

```
{"markers": [ 
    {"text":"Ondertekenen koopverkoopcontract", "latitude":-12.917239,     "longtitude":-38.48209},
    {"text":"Openen documentair krediet", "latitude":51.218584, "longtitude":4.40413},
    {"text":"Transport van producent naar haven Salvador", "latitude":51.22952, "longtitude":4.411617},
    {"text":"Vertrek naar haven Antwerpen", "latitude":-12.968114, "longtitude":-38.511543},
    {"text":"Aankomst haven Antwerpen + vertrek naar Transibel", "latitude":51.22952, "longtitude":4.411617},
    {"text":"Aankomst Transibel", "latitude":51.094863, "longtitude":4.12973},
    {"text" : "center point", "latitude":28.767659, "longtitude":-31.640625}
]}
```

I cannot see any markers on my map. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with google maps api, but what is `centerBegin` and where `;` in end of line?

Comment: just forgot to comment that one :) but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the sample code you've posted.

1. Iterating over `data`, when you really want to iterate over `data['markers']`.  If you look at your JSON file you'll see it's not an `array`, but an `object` whose `markers` element is holding an `array` of marker info.
2. Over-use of the `marker` variable, like graphicdivine pointed out.

Comment: @Sixx, if this answer works you should select this as the chosen answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're re-declaring `marker` inside the `each` loop, as highlighted below.

```
$.each(data, function (i, marker) {
//--------------------------^
    // [...]
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
//--------^
```

Comment: This can be a part of the solution, but this didn't fix the problem.